# Right approach when the values of a predictor might differ for repeated measurements?

Tags: interaction

We took 2 samples (sweep netting) of bee communities on 30 vegetable fields at 2 time steps (during early flowering and shortly before harvest). After the vegetables were harvested we asked the farmers how often they applied pesticides.

Now I want to model the effect on the number of pesticide applications on the abundance of bees. The issue is that I don't know when the pesticide application took place. But I assume that the majority of applications did happen between our 2 samples. I also have additional landscape predictors that are the same for both samples.

What do you think would be the best way to model this?
I could either do 2 separate models (2 x 30 obs) for each sample that includes the landscape predictors but only the second one includes the pesticide variable. Or I fit a single model (60 obs) with sample as fixed effect and site as random effect, as well an interaction term sample:pesticides.
If I use a single model with an interaction term, this is the resulting interaction plot (the pesticide variable is scaled by the way...)

[image]

It kind of makes sense. But it is confusing on first glance. So I would love to get some opinions on this. I also wondered if there is some sort of best practice for situations like this.

Cheers!